# HKObjectQuery completion handler only triggered when watch is active?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

With the code below I am querying for `distanceWalkingAndRunning` samples on the Apple Watch, which I want to return to me (i.e. the completion handler getting called in real time as the user is moving), however, in testing...when I move, the completion handler isn't called, it's only called when I raise my wrist and activate the watch?  I want this data collecting in the background if possible.  The query is triggered when the workout starts,  none of this is tied to the `awake` or `willActivate` functions?

```
func startWalkingRunningQuery(from startDate: Date, updateHandler: @escaping ([HKQuantitySample]) -> Void) {
        let typeIdentifier = HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning
        startQuery(ofType: typeIdentifier, from: startDate) { _, samples, _, _, error in
            guard let quantitySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
                print("Distance walking running query failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            updateHandler(quantitySamples)

        }
    }

  //Generic helper function 
    private func startQuery(ofType type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier, from startDate: Date, handler: @escaping
        (HKAnchoredObjectQuery, [HKSample]?, [HKDeletedObject]?, HKQueryAnchor?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let datePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: nil, options: .strictStartDate)
        let devicePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: [HKDevice.local()])
        let queryPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[datePredicate, devicePredicate])

        let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: type)!

        let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: queryPredicate, anchor: nil,
                                          limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, resultsHandler: handler)
        query.updateHandler = handler
        healthStore.execute(query)

        activeDataQueries.append(query)
    }
```

Comment: Does your app start a workout session?

Comment: Yes I am starting a workout session